# Is There A Way to Apple App Store Verify Frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, app-store

**MY DILEMMA:**

I tend to write in a very modular fashion, creating frameworks and SDKs to be used by contractors and third parties.

I write in systems, not apps, so this model is important.

A few years ago, I wrote an Objective-C static library that used BSD sockets to communicate with devices over a specialized WiFi setup. It used HTTP, but had some quirks that required the low-level stuff, and the devices didn't use HTTPS.

Back then, that was OK. I doubt that an app that uses that library would pass App Store review, nowadays.

I'm in the midst of writing another framework now. I doubt it will have the same issues, as everything is being done using high-level stuff, but I'd still like to be able to verify that when I send my app out into the world (probably as a CocoaPod), I won't be giving anyone a dependency that could cause their app to fail validation.

Is there a way to do an App Store Verify on components? Is there a test tool that I haven't seen that could scan for things that could fail validation?

**WHAT I HAVE CONSIDERED**

The natural first thought is to create a test harness, and submit that for validation, but never release it.

There's another problem: You can't delete unreleased apps from the App Store. I have a bug report in about it, but I suspect that it is not *a priori* with Apple. It's still lying fallow after a couple of years.

I have quite a few apps, and several of them are zombies. It's annoying.

So I am loathe to submit a test harness, and end up with yet another zombie.

I know that the Apple dev system is loaded with all kinds of CLI utils that aren't documented. I can't find any with my searching, but I may be using the wrong search terms.

Anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Replace one of your "zombie" apps with your test harness app? (Use the same bundle id)

Comment: That's a consideration. I was thinking about creating a general-purpose "test app". I'll greencheck that if you submit it as an answer.

Comment: FWIW, there is no problem with App Store review for apps that disable ATS if there is a good reason. Interfacing with hardware that doesn't support TLS and could be on an arbitrary address is good reason.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah...not my problem anymore. That library is way out of my hands, nowadays, and I do try to keep as high-level as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create another "zombie" app, you could replace one of the existing ones with your test harness app. As long as you keep the same bundle id, you can change anything else (name, etc).

Comment: Just wanted to report on this. It works beautifully. I was able to repurpose the two "zombies," and Apple has approved them for beta-testing; which is all I wanted.